# Query objects with unknown selector fieldnames in Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

All the example cloudant query selectors in that documentation and that I can find have known field names, e.g:

```
{
  "selector": {
       "name": "John"
  },
  ......
}
```

I've got a document that's a collection of objects named with the user's email address, like so:

```
{
   "_id":  "nnnnnn",
   "_rev": "nnnnnnn",
   "bill@anon.com": {
       "name": "William Smith",
       "age":  25
   },
   "jane@gmail.com" {
       "name": "Jane Doe",
       "age":  27
   }
   ....
}
```

I want to do a selector that wildcards the object name so that it's functionally equivalent to

```
{
  "selector": {
       "*.age": { "$gt": 21 }
  },
  ......
}
```

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You could accomplish this with a traditional CouchDB view. I don't think the Mango queries will support it, though.

Comment: Are you willing to frob your data model such that those people are contained by an array? Something like this:
{"_id":"nnn",
"_rev":"nnn",
"people":[
{
"email":"jane@gmail.com",
"name":"Jane Doe"
},
{
"email":"bill@anon.com",
"name":"William Smith"
}
]
}

If so, guidance is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709358/cloudant-mango-selector-for-deeply-nested-jsons