# CouchDB query selector on string in array of elements

Tags: couchdb

I need to get the documents where exists `Archery` in the array list of `games`. How can i do with CouchDB selector?

```
[{
    "name": "John",
    "games": ["Archery", "Board sports"]
},
{
    "name": "Sara",
    "games": ["Fishing", "Archery"]
},
{
    "name": "Tara",
    "games": ["Decathlon"]
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloudant Selector Query for fetching particular elements inside Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460879/cloudant-selector-query-for-fetching-particular-elements-inside-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch`:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "games": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "$eq": "Archery"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It will return all objects where `games` field equals 'Archery'