# Cloudant-client query with nested array fields using #elemMatch selector

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant

Is it possible to create the same query explained here: [Cloudant Selector Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262573/cloudant-selector-query/33835521) using the next java client: https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the query selector string to the [query method](https://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.17.0/com/cloudant/client/api/Database.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) e.g.

```java
String selector = "{\"selector\":{\"loansBorrowed\":{\"$elemMatch\":{\"loanamount\":{\"$gt\":1000}}}}}";
QueryResult<ProfileDocumentPojo> result = db.query(selector, ProfileDocumentPojo.class);
List<ProfileDocumentPojo> profiles = result.getDocs();
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I do now. But is it possible to create this query programmatically using QueryBuilder?

Comment: It's currently not supported by QueryBuilder.